# Attachments embedded inside the PDF file does not open/preview in Chrome pdf viewer

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, adobe, attachment

I have a PDF file having embedded documents attached.

I am not able to download the attachments or view the attachments embedded within the PDF file from Chrome.

However, I am able to download the attachments if i right click on the link and use 'save link as' menu to save the file.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

You're already doing it. The native Chrome PDF viewer simply doesn't support attachments. You can't even see that they're there. You have to download the file and open it in a more capable viewer.

Comment: Attachments were still missing when downloaded from chrome pdf viewer and opened in Adobe PDF reader.

Comment: Can you post the PDF in question?

Comment: Sorry, cant post the PDF

Comment: Firefox's PDF viewer supports viewing/downloading attachments.